# Why Index + Match + Maxifs not working for weekends (day name)

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I'm using the formula below to get the qty of the last day matching the weekday name and the product code.
It works fine for weekdays, but on the weekend days, it brings only the first occurrence, repeating it down the rows, despite the product code criteria changes.

```
=arrayformula(INDEX('Inventory'!$B$7:$M;(MATCH(MAXIFS('Inventory'!$B$7:$B;'Inventory'!$M$7:$M;L$6;'Inventory'!$D$7:$D;$C7);'Inventory'!$B$7:$B;0));7))
```

Here's the table it brings values from:

|N  |Date   |Resp|Cód. Produto|Descrição Produto|Lote|Unid.|Qtd.|PreçoUnit|Total|Data de Validade|Local|Weekday

Could anyone point out where the flaw sits in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks, @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_E_PHh_Q8EkoSha6ECkvHB3bJA1VtdOEJG_jHV856eo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey, it would be nice to understand why your formula wasn't working? Could you share a copy of your original sheet?

Comment: Hi, @fullfine! Just got it out of the trash. See link right in the comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use in L7:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP($C$7:$C; SORTN(QUERY(SORT(
 {'Entrada - Estoque'!$B$7:$B\ 'Entrada - Estoque'!$D$7:$D\ 'Entrada - Estoque'!$H$7:$H\ TEXT('Entrada - Estoque'!$B$7:$B; "ddd")}; 1; 0; 2; 1); 
 "select Col2,Col3 where Col4 = '"&L6&"' and Col3 is not null"); 9^9; 2; 1; 1); 2; 0)/SUM(INDEX(SORTN(QUERY(SORT(
 {'Entrada - Estoque'!$B$7:$B\ 'Entrada - Estoque'!$D$7:$D\ 'Entrada - Estoque'!$H$7:$H\ TEXT('Entrada - Estoque'!$B$7:$B; "ddd")}; 1; 0; 2; 1); 
 "select Col2,Col3 where Col4 = '"&L6&"' and Col3 is not null"); 9^9; 2; 1; 1);;2))))
```

[image]

Comment: Insane! Thanks again!